# Build a function to remove minimum and maximum values in the data set based on cutoff?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe. In that for few columns I want to remove values less than and greater than certain cutoff.

Ex: I want to remove rows with "price" column data less than 500 and greater 20000, also "area" column data less than 20 and greater than 1000

cutoffs looks like this : `[('price', 500, 20000), ('area', 20, 1000)]`

I need to build a function in python which does that.

```
data = data_frame
cut = cutoffs

for a in range(len(cut)):
    data = data[data[cut[a][0] >= cut[a][1]]]

for b in range(len(cut)):
    data = data[data[cut[b][0] <= cut[b][2]]]
    return data
```

this is not working the way I expected. Some how I need to combine the less than and greater than condition and unable to figure it out

Comment: `df.loc[df['price'].between(50, 20000) & df['area'].between(20, 1000)]` ?

Comment: i am looking to write a function. cutoffs can have more rows, each row will have name, min, and max value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention that `cutoffs` can have more rows you can do this:

```
for name, min, max in cutoffs:
  df = df[~(df[name] < min) & ~(df[name] > max)]
```

If you want a function for the same, try:

```
def apply_cutoffs(df, cutoffs)
  for name, min, max in cutoffs:
    df = df[~(df[name] < min) & ~(df[name] > max)]
  return df
```

Calling it like this:

```
df = apply_cutoffs(df, cutoffs)
```